# What do the language word types means here?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a site that could help me with the language tests and found this one:

http://www.jlptstudy.net/N5/?vocab-list

One thing I am confused by is the type column of this grid. Can anyone tell me what they think int, u-v and the other values mean?

Comment: There is a cross-reference guide to these terms available here: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/glossary-simple-linguistics-terms-and-cross-reference/933#933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether your question is on-topic here.

'int' means interjection. 'u-v' means a verb with an ending of 'u' as in 'あう' and 'いう' or 'u' sound as in '[要る]{いる}'. 'ru-v' is a verb with an ending of 'ru' as in '[入れる]{いれる}'. You will be able to figure out what the others are for.

Comment: These 'ru-verbs' are in proper parlance ichidan verbs, and 'u-verbs' are godan verbs. The textbook publishers just insist on having the most confusing terminology available. I'm not sure why this web site chose to follow their example.

Comment: Well, to be fair, "ichidan" and "godan" are Japanese words and not transparent to beginners... and "monograde" etc. isn't much better. Descriptive names are more useful for the 95% of people who just need a scaffolding to start talking. (That said "ru-v" could stand to be a bit clearer itself.)

Comment: I wouldn't mind if they called them group 1 and group 5, but they keep creating crisscrossing terminology such as 'group 1' (5-dan) and 'group 2' (1-dan) which is what gets me.

Comment: The *u* and *ru* terms make perfect sense if taught as part of a coherent framework.  要る is *ir-u*, while 居る is *i-ru*.  Add the negator *-(a)nai*, and you get 要らない *ir-anai* and 居ない *i-nai*.  But this sort of discussion doesn't work in the traditional kana-bound framework of Japanese school grammar.

Comment: Group 1 and Group 2 vs 5dan and 1dan is pretty confusing, yeah. But "group 5" would be worse, because it implies there are more groups than there are! In conclusion, "vowel-stem" and "consonant-stem" 4 life.